# Ejabberd can't register new user

Tags: macos, xmpp, ejabberd

I am on mac using latest version of mac OS (Mavericks.) I downloaded `ejabberd 13.12` for mac, installed it, and started it through terminal. Now i can open it in browser (i am using mozilla firefox 26 and latest safari). and went to admin console.

Everything seems fine, i can log in with my user name and password (which i provided during jabber installation). Now i went to access control lists, and try to add additonal users. Problem is i can't.

In mozilla i get error message, that connection with server was reset, and on safari i get blank page. After I refresh new users are not there. Here is the screen i am talking about:

[image]

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

This is the error message i get:

```
2014-02-05 16:29:39.204 [error] <0.428.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.428.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: no case clause matching 
{error,{aborted,{{case_clause,{user,<<"brad">>,<<"donjohnson">>}},
[{acl,normalize_spec,1,[{file,"src/acl.erl"},{line,222}]},{acl,'-add_list_local/3-fun-  1-',2,[{file,"src/acl.erl"},{line,157}]},{lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1323}]},
{mnesia_tm,apply_fun,3,[{file,"mnesia_tm.erl"},{line,832}]},
{mnesia_tm,execute_transaction,5,[{file,"mnesia_tm.erl"},{line,812}]},{rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,[{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,205}]}]}}} in  ejabberd_web_admin:process_admin/2 line 700
```

Comment: Is there any error message in the ejabberd log files?

Comment: Yes, I will update my question with it.

Comment: So the function `acl:normalize_spec` expects to get a rule of the form `{user, {Username, Hostname}}`, but it gets `{user, Username, Hostname}` instead.  Not sure why; hopefully someone more knowledgeable about ejabberd will see this and enlighten us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more information see [github](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/cd0381bab5c83f8fc7a6a81412f201d85a3d4ffa).

Also I may be going out on a limb here, but are you trying to add  users to the server or users to the ACLs?

If you are just trying to add users, do this from your `Virtual Hosts -> (Host) -> Users` area. 

If you are in fact trying to add ACLs you could try adding them in the `ejabberd.cfg` file.

Comment: It seems you are right. I think i you have earned your bounty. Since I am really newbie to all this. Can you expand on your answer a little. What is ACL, and what it means to add users to acl?

Comment: ACL stands for access control list, and it basically does exactly what it says. It allows you to create lists that control if and how people access your server. For example when you first set up your server, you put `admin@donjohnson` into the list that controls who has administrator rights.

Comment: Thanks @jokker, you saved me hours ignoring the `Virtual Hosts` button :) By the way, is there any way to manage user info such as a name, surname or avatar from the web panel?

Comment: @ssantos You ain't lying! I had no clue I'd have to go to that link first before adding a user.

Answer (score 1):

As jokker mentioned, you are in ACL menu, not in register menu.

To fix error you posted in ACL menu, source code should be patched.

```
--- a/src/ejabberd_web_admin.erl
+++ b/src/ejabberd_web_admin.erl
@@ -1138,7 +1138,7 @@ string_to_spec2(ACLName, Val) ->
        jlib:string_to_jid(Val),
     case U of
       <<"">> -> {ACLName, S};
-      _ -> {ACLName, U, S}
+      _ -> {ACLName, {U, S}}
     end.
```

It seems that other `string_to_spec` function should be fixed.