# Adding new user to ejabberd through Smack android api

Tags: java, android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I have installed [ejabberd](https://www.ejabberd.im/) on my local server. This was then tested in spark for its functionality and it worked fine. Now I want to add a new user through the android app.

I tried adding a new user through spark and it worked fine. The fields I have given are `uesrname`, `password`, `confirm password`, `server`. But when I tried to do it using the [smack api](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/) in the android app it gave the following error:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: forbidden - auth
```

I was using [createAccount()](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.0.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html#createAccount(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), seen in the code I was using below, to create the new account in smack.

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(conn1);

try {
    accountManager.createAccount("tryuser", "qwerty");
    Log.i("log", "created user successfully");
} catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have checked if it supports new account creation by [supportsAccountCreation()](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.0.6/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html#supportsAccountCreation()) and it returned `true`.

I have changed my `register` rule to `allow all` in ejabberd server. and i don't think it has any problem because i can create account from spark, but getting error in smack.

I have looked into the following SO questions related to this topic but no luck.

- [Ejabberd can't register new user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556507/ejabberd-cant-register-new-user)
- [How to register a new user on XMPP using (a)Smack library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476867/how-to-register-a-new-user-on-xmpp-using-asmack-library/7140370#7140370)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: you can create user directly by inserting record in the the database. create Webservice and send the user data to the server. I was doing this a long time ago with openfire.

Comment: hey @DevendraSingh please give some example on this .

Comment: i dont want to do any webservice . it should from my app not any webview.

Comment: better way is create api(don't need to use webview) call the webservice insert the record in the user table of the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give a try with below -

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
                try {
                    if (accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()) {
                        accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
                        accountManager.createAccount("userName", "password");

                    }
                } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And you also need to set below in ejabberd.cfg (config file)

```
{access, register, [{allow, all}]}.
```

which means - In-band registration allows registration of any possible username. To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.

And in mod_register (module in same config file) please set below -

```
{access_from, register}
```

& before that please check you are connected to XMPP server.

Probably this will resolve your issue.

Comment: accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);

is the key to non-ssl connections